# Div not getting fixed on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a `div` fixed to top when I scroll down. But somehow the code is not working...

Please check the code below:

```
<div id="column-left" class="column_absolute">
      My name is Peter
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function window_onload() {
    alert("hi");
    window.addEventListener("scroll", navbar_reset_top, false); 
}

var navbar_top = 100;
function navbar_reset_top() {

    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > navbar_top && column-left.className === "column_absolute") {
        document.getElementById("column-left").className="column_fixed";
    }
    else if (scrollTop < navbar_top && column-left.className === "column_fixed") {
        document.getElementById("column-left").className="column_absolute";
    }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.column_absolute {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0px 15px 0 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:absolute;
}
.column_fixed {
    width: 220px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding: 0px 15px 0 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:window_onload()">
```

When I'm scrolling down, the `div` mentioned above should be fixed.

Please check the code and correct me please...

Comment: You're using `column-left` in your JS code, but it's not defined *anywhere*.

Comment: i defined #column-left as well in my code.but still it didnt wrk

Comment: No, no, in your **JavaScript** code. You're using `column-left.className` but `column-left` is undefined. You need a `document.getElementById` to target that element.

Comment: ya.gt that clue man...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine in your code, except that you have `undefined variable column-left`. Probably you missed defining it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/137/

```
function window_onload() {
    alert("hi");
    document.addEventListener("scroll", navbar_reset_top, false);
}
var navbar_top = 100;

function navbar_reset_top() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var column_left = document.getElementById("column-left");
    if (scrollTop > navbar_top && column_left.className === "column_absolute") {
        document.getElementById("column-left").className = "column_fixed";
    } else if (scrollTop < navbar_top && column_left.className === "column_fixed") {
        document.getElementById("column-left").className = "column_absolute";
    }
}
```

I used `column_left` instead of `column-left`

Answer (score 0):

the id of the div is column_fixed. you should use # insead of . in your css class to use id selector.

```
 #column_fixed
 {

 width: 220px;
 position:fixed;
 margin-top:0px;
 padding: 0px 15px 0 0px;
 border-right: 1px solid #eee;

}
```

Comment: but the id is column-left only ,its not column_fixed

Comment: Why? He has an element with an **id** of `column-left`, to which he either adds the **class** `column_absolute` *or* `columng_fixed`.

Comment: column_absolute uses absolute position and not fixed which means it won't be sticky